# How to create sub set of controllers / routes in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

What would be the correct syntax in CakePHP for sending all routes with an "api" prefix to an API controllers sub folder? According to the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) it appears that this should be done through a prefix route. I have tried this code:

```
Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions('json');
    $routes->resources('TennantGoogleProfiles');

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
    $routes->connect('/login/*', ['controller' => 'Logins', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->connect('/logout', ['controller' => 'Logins', 'action' => 'logout']);

    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    // Should route all /api/asset routes to src/Controller/Api/AssetController.php
    $routes->prefix('api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->resources('Asset');
    });

    // Routes all controllers within src/Controller, was left in code from previous developers
    $routes->fallbacks(InflectedRoute::class);
});
```

The routes dump for this looks like:

```
| api:asset:index                     | /api/asset                              | {"_method":"GET","action":"index","controller":"Asset","plugin":null,"prefix":"api"}           |
| api:asset:add                       | /api/asset                              | {"_method":"POST","action":"add","controller":"Asset","plugin":null,"prefix":"api"}            |
| api:asset:view                      | /api/asset/:id                          | {"_method":"GET","action":"view","controller":"Asset","plugin":null,"prefix":"api"}            |
| api:asset:edit                      | /api/asset/:id                          | {"_method":["PUT","PATCH"],"action":"edit","controller":"Asset","plugin":null,"prefix":"api"}  |
| api:asset:delete                    | /api/asset/:id                          | {"_method":"DELETE","action":"delete","controller":"Asset","plugin":null,"prefix":"api"}
```

And am getting this error:

```
Error: A route matching "array ( 'controller' => 'UserLogins', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => 'api', 'plugin' => NULL, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.
```

For whatever reason this seems to expect the login routes to be defined in the prefix block as well.

I have looked around a bit on the web, and seen a few different ways of doing this. But all of them seem to be giving me this result.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: First things first, whenever you have routing problems, check what routes exactly are connected and in which order: `bin/cake routes` (**https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/routes-shell.html**). That being said, you won't find a route that maps to `/api/asset` in your routes, as that's not what nested do create, check the examples in the docs that you've linked, it will connect URLs like `/api/:api_id/asset ` and `/api/:api_id/asset/:id`. So the first question I'd have, would be whether you actually need nested resource routes, ie an "api id" in your asset controller actions?

Comment: My bad I see exactly what you mean, it would actually be an API prefix that I am trying to get. I would like the routes to work like /api/asset/:id. I will update my question.

Comment: Your updated example should work fine, unless there's additional routes before the ones you're showing, which could catch the URL. What exactly is happening when you browse to `/api/asset`?

Comment: "Error: A route matching "array ( 'controller' => 'UserLogins', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => 'api', 'plugin' => NULL, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found." is the error. I guess it is working and for whatever reason it expects the login routes above to be in the API prefix block as well, as it works when I copy it into there. I am looking into it more now.

Comment: I have adjusted the question to reflect the error message.

Comment: I think you have somewhere bad redirect to "UserLogins" controller